# MySql recovering deleted table

Tags: mysql

Unfortunately I cleanUp one of the tables on my database and i'm trying to recover it with the `mysqlbinlog` command on mysql cli, as i just learned that. How can i recover it? my below command couldn't execute

command:

```
mysqlbinlog binary_log_file > query_log.sql
```

terminal:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> mysqlbinlog binary_log_file > query_log.sql
    -> 
    -> Ctrl-C -- exit!
```

how can i execute this command on sql cli?